# Regex for this string format

Tags: c#, regex

What is the correct c# regex for the following string:

8:13-bk-99999

8 can also be a 2 digit number 08 or 10, always numeric

99999 can be 3 digits to 5 digits, all numeric

bk can be any 2 alpha characters, case insensitive

Thanks

Comment: What have your tried yourself?

Comment: Yes, I tried it on http://regexhero.net/tester/ .... my problem was I had highlighted my target string with the mouse and so no matter what I typed into the above box, it never showed as a match (the blue highlight was over riding the yellow), which caused me to think I was completely off-base.

Comment: This shouldn't have been closed. It was specific in the problem, it was clear, it wasn't about a "simple typographical error", it can be reproduced (the problem is the lack of understanding of regex). It isn't a good question, tho, and should be downvoted (as I have helped with).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as you asked for a C# example, Case Insensitive can be selected as one of the `RegexOptions`.

I assumed the `13` was also meant to be a 2 digit number.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

Regex regX = new Regex(
    @"(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})-([a-z]{2})-(\d{3,5})",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
);

if( regX.IsMatch( inputString ) )
{
    // Matched
}

...
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
\d{1,2}:\d{2}-[A-Za-z]{2}-\d{3,5}
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/lE4sP8

Answer (score 0):

Pattern:

```
(\b(8|08|10):\d{2}-[a-zA-Z]{2}-\d{3,5}\b)
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace myapp
{
  class Class1
    {
      static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          String sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
          Regex re = new Regex(@"(\b(8|08|10):\d{2}-[a-zA-Z]{2}-\d{3,5}\b)",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
          Match m = re.Match(sourcestring);
          for (int gIdx = 0; gIdx < m.Groups.Count; gIdx++)
            {
              Console.WriteLine("[{0}] = {1}", re.GetGroupNames()[gIdx], m.Groups[gIdx].Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

example: http://www.myregextester.com/?r=bbf584e8

The other examples don't seem to take into account numbers starting with more than two digits, or ending with more than five, they just grab what is in-between them. I would presume you wouldn't want `00:11-00-aa-00000`, taken from `000:11-00-aa-000000`.